# Importing xlwt generated excel files into SAS

Tags: python, excel, sas, xlwt

I converted a bunch of csv files into excel files using xlwt.
After that I need to import these excel files to SAS (statistical software).

On first try SAS throws an error saying that file format is invalid.

But when I just open any of generated files with MS Excel and close without doing any changes and without saving the file is imported in SAS successfully.

I found that MS Excel changes file header adding there the current username and updates file modified date.

I wonder if there is any possibility to modify excel file binary header before saving it.

Update:
I am using xlwt version 0.7.4, 
Python 2.7.3, 
SAS 9.3,
Excel 2010,
Windows 7 32bit.

This is part of the my code where I convert CSV to Excel:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='latin-1')
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
sourceCSV = csv.reader(open(files, 'rb'), delimiter=";")
for rowi, row in enumerate(sourceCSV):
    for coli, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(rowi, coli, value)
wb.save(xls_file)
```

Here are options being used with SAS import function:

```
...
DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
RANGE="Sheet1$";
GETNAMES=YES;
MIXED=NO;
SCANTEXT=YES;
USEDATE=YES;
SCANTIME=YES;
...
```

This is the error SAS produces:

```
ERROR: Connect: External table is not in expected format. 
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

Comment: How are you using SAS to access the Excel file? ie: the ODBC extension (Note - I haven't used SAS since 2004!)

Comment: On an aside - you're probably better off just importing the CSV data into SAS

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, SAS is being used by statisticians and as they described the problem with importing csv files is that SAS sets the field size based on the first raw of CSV file. If later in the document there are longer strings in this field SAS has problems processing them.
Excel files are imported using SAS query language as I saw. Not sure if my definition is correct though.

Comment: I believe it's possible to explicitly set the lengths though (ie $char100.)... If not - another option is to convert the CSV to fixed length records, and produce a bit of code suitable for use in the `infile`/`input` statement... (like I say, I'm rusty, though) - if it's a problem with `xlwt` then it does have its own mailing list as well which the creator of the project responds to, so that may be worth considering...

Comment: Hi, I'm the xlwt maintainer. Can you quote the exact error message that you get from SAS? What version of xlwt are you using? Please show the code that you wrote to convert your CSV files into XLS files. Please show a small (2 or three rows) csv file that causes the problem.

Comment: @JonClements : Thanks, I think the solution was posted below. They were not using guessingrows option. Waiting for the feedback from statisticians.

Comment: @JohnMachin , I have updated my question. I can't add sample from CSV but it contains numbers and strings in the same column so SAS determines column's type and size incorrectly. 
I think solution was posted below but it would be interesting to find out what it si that xlwt generated xls files are missing. Or at least what SAS thinks is missing.

Comment: Your error message from SAS says "Error in the LIBNAME statement". You have not shown the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: Possibly nothing to do with your problem, but you are in a Windows environment and so the chance that your data is actually encoded in latin1 is near zero. I suggest that you do `import locale; print locale.getpreferredencoding()` (mine returns `cp1252`) and use that instead of `latin1`.

Comment: @JohnMachin thanks for the hint about locale. I tried 'ascii' and 'utf-8' first but in both cases error was returned:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 13: invalid start byte`
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)`
`locale.getpreferredencoding()` returned `cp1257` for me and all files were converted without error.

Comment: Have you tried the resulting files with SAS?

Comment: Not yet. Going to try tomorrow. Will report results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If opening the workbook in Excel and saving it allows SAS to import it properly, that would indicate (to me) that there is some defect in `xlxt` (a process I know nothing about).  Importing Excel files into SAS is a complicated topic because of the many different types of Excel workbooks.

It would be much easier to read the CSV file directly and skip the conversion to Excel.  When you use **PROC IMPORT** to read a CSV file, SAS inspects to first several rows of the file to determine the column types.  By default, SAS will look only at the first 20 rows in the file but you can change that with the **GUESSINGROWS** statement:

```
proc import datafile="C:\temp\test.csv"
     out=mydataset
     dbms=csv
     replace;
     getnames=yes;  /* Uses first row in CSV for column names */
     guessingrows=32767; 
run;
```

The above is the max value for **GUESSINGROWS** for version 9.2 of SAS; if you are using 9.3, the max has increased to 2,147,483,647.

Comment: Definitely go the CSV route.  Converting to Excel to get it into SAS is like rotting your banana before eating it.  SAS will work far better with CSV format than with excel.  You can also hand-write theinput code rather than use PROC IMPORT; then you can specify every single column format/length directly.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a good solution. I talked to statisticians and they were not using 'guessingrows' parameter. Waiting for update from them.